# Why do I get the "Array subscript is not an integer" error?

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
void capturat(i vec[5])

{ 

    float i; for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
      printf("Dame los tiempos 5 maximo:\t");
      scanf("%f",&vec[i]);
    }
}

float imprimet(float vec[5])

{

     float i;
     for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            printf("Tu tiempo es %f \n",vec[i]);
        }
}
```

The compiler says that I have an "array subscript is not an integer" in the functions `capturat()` and `imprimet()`.

Comment: this line: `void capturat(i vec[5])` is not valid,  perhaps you meant: `void capturat(float vec[5])`

Comment: for readability and understandability by us humans, only one statement per line.  So this: `float i; for (i=0;i<=5;i++)` should be two lines.

Comment: when calling the system function: `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  In this case use: `if( 1 != scanf("%f",&vec[i]) ) { perror("scanf() failed"); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  Where the 1 is the number of format specifiers in the format parameter

Answer (score 2):

you should use integer for your loop counter i
as array subscript has to be integer

```
int i; 
for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    printf("Dame los tiempos 5 maximo:\t");
    scanf("%f",&vec[i]);
}
```

Comment: Also warn the OP about his mistake on the loop test.  The code invokes undefined behaviour.